# Why am I sentenced to the captcha thing if I forget to login?

Tags: support, login, captcha

Typical scenario:

- I check questions on SO without logging in(*)
- I find a question for which I have an answer
- I write an answer
- I figure out I'm not logged in
- I login (and SO keeps my input)
- I submit... and I get a captcha.

So why suddenly is this authenticated user with a somewhat flattering kharma assumed to be a bot?

(*) because I haven't yet found a way to auto-login..

Comment: I thought logging in was universal. And I'm auto logged in all the time. What sorta login? SE?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me.

Comment: @FleetCommand: it's trivial to reproduce by copying and pasting.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Browser cache / cookies allows to stay logged in

Comment: It is a reward, not a sentence.

Comment: _"a somewhat flattering kharma"_ y'wot?

Comment: I like how you've used *sentenced* instead of *subjected* :D

Comment: @xenoid Have you ever considered that you might not be human? :P

Comment: @caimen Of course I'm not, my nickname means "alien form" in Greek... But that doesn't make me a robot.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's because you posted too fast after logging in.

The system thinks you might be a robot because humans are not usually that fast to post that much text right after logging in, but robots *are*.

You can reproduce this by copying a larger piece of text, opening a new page (be it existing question or the ask page), immediately pasting and hitting the submit button; loading a page and immediately posting also counts as 'robot-like'.

I know this because [once upon a time Stack Exchange tried to talk to me in robot language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209460/stack-overflow-knows-i-am-a-robot-and-greets-me-in-robot-language) every time my mobile network reconnected just as I was posting.

Comment: OK, so what is the delay? How much should I wait?

Comment: @xenoid: I never timed it. Not all that long; you can try to find a ballpark figure by posting to the [MSE sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). I suspect it is no more that a minute at most.